# JBoss 7.1 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child container with name already exists

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, war

I am using JBoss AS 7.1 & trying to deploy a war. But i am getting following exception :

```
17:12:11,146 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child container with name  already exists
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:804)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:356)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:38)
    at org.jboss.msc.inject.CastingInjector.inject(CastingInjector.java:55) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.doInject(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1549) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$1900(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.performInjections(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1741) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more

17:12:11,356 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "amft.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service"}}
```

I am using following standalone.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="10000"/>
    </system-properties>

    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DefaultDS" pool-name="DefaultDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@test.com:1991/test</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>app_owner</user-name>
                        <password>app_owner</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-exploded="false"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.1" default-cache-container="hibernate">
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="false"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
            <show-model value="true"/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
            <properties>
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">
                    1
                </property>
            </properties>
            <capabilities>
                <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
                <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
            </capabilities>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" native="false" default-virtual-server="default-host">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

I tried reinstalling JBoss, but still getting the same exception while the deployment.
I already tried changing

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
to <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
```

But with this change, my application doesn't work in a right way.

I need to make it work with `<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">`

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work in a right way" with the false value? Would you mind being more specific?

Comment: It doesn't load the values from the DB. It doesn't display any exception in server logs. But there is no data.

Comment: Also the war was getting deployed properly without enable-welcome-root="true"
but i hot-deployed some changes using Eclipse JBoss AS tool. That caused the issue.

Comment: I have also tried re-installing JBoss AS entirely. The problem still persists. This bothers me a lot.

Comment: What is your context-root defined as? jboss-web.xml

Comment: Yes. That solved the issue..i changed the context-root in jboss-web.xml and it start working. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I was able to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing context root for a web app under JBoss As 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081347/changing-context-root-for-a-web-app-under-jboss-as-7)

Comment: I switched enable-welcome-root="true" in standalone.xml to false, and everything works.

Answer (score 5):

Following could be the reason

1. There may be more than two wars with same "context-root"
2. Check if your context path are pointing to default context-root which could cause this problem

To solve this, give different context-root in the Jboss-web.xml for different wars